# TSQL Using CAST to convert a string to an List of integers

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string called `stringIDs` which is returned from a C# program and the string looks like this: "'1','2','3','4'"

I have a table whose col1 values are 1,2,3,4 (integers)

I have the following SQl code in C#

```
sql = $"SELECT col1, col2 from dbo.databas1 WHERE col1 in in CAST({stringIds} AS INT";
```

I am not able to use Cast to convert the string to a integers. Can someone tell me how to convert that string so that Where clause implementation can happen?

Comment: Well you could just format the string to `"1, 2, 3, 4"` and then just `col1 in ({stringIds})`.  But it would be much better to parse out the individual ints and pass them each as a parameter.

Comment: Actually Worked by modifying my string output.

Comment: I don't know where your source data is coming from but if you trust it and you're 100% confident your source data will always contains only ints then it should be safe to let SQL Server do an implicit cast here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (without casting):

```
sql = $"SELECT col1, col2 from dbo.databas1 WHERE col1 in ({stringIds})";
```